# Snowflake Stored Procedure For Loop

Tags: loops, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i'm working with Snowflake,
i created this Stored Procedure, it's purpose is to do the following steps:

1. extract the relevant 'application_id' values from the SQL query
2. use a FOR loop over a SQL query, with the 'application_id' values that i extracted
   in step 1, and delete the relevant rows from the target table.

when i call the Stored Procedure, it runs without errors, but it doesn't do anything ( the relevant records are not been deleted).

i added my SP code,
please let me know if you see any syntax / logic errors,
thanks

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DWH.sp_testing()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE javascript
strict
EXECUTE AS owner
AS
$$

try 
{
    var application_list = ` SELECT  application_id
                             FROM PUBLIC.my_source_table_name
                             WHERE my_flag = 1
                           `

    var query_statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: application_list});
    var application_list_result = query_statement.execute();

    for (i = 1; i <= query_statement.getRowCount(); i++) 
    {
        application_list_result.next()
        application_id = application_list_result.getColumnValue(1)   
         

        var delete_daily_records = `
                                DELETE FROM PUBLIC.my_target_table_name AS target
                                WHERE target.application_id = ${application_id}
                            `

        snowflake.execute({sqlText: delete_daily_records});
    }

}

catch (err) 
{
    throw "Failed: " + err; 
}

$$
;

CALL DWH.sp_testing();
```

Comment: Check the query history to see what is the query being run and that would give you an idea where this is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your query is returning data? Also are you sure the target table has data matching your DELETE statement?

The following test works for me using your stored procedure:

```
select count(*) from citibike_trips where end_station_id=6215;
```

returns: 14565

Now, I created your stored proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_testing()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE javascript
strict
EXECUTE AS owner
AS
$$

try 
{
    var application_list = `SELECT  end_station_id
                            FROM citibike_trips
                            WHERE end_station_id=6215 limit 10
                           `

    var query_statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: application_list});
    var application_list_result = query_statement.execute();

    for (i = 1; i <= query_statement.getRowCount(); i++) 
    {
        application_list_result.next()
        end_station_id = application_list_result.getColumnValue(1)
        
         

        var delete_daily_records = `
                                DELETE FROM citibike_trips AS target
                                WHERE target.end_station_id = ${end_station_id}
                            `

        snowflake.execute({sqlText: delete_daily_records});
    }
}
catch (err) 
{
    throw "Failed: " + err; 
}

$$
;
```

Run it:

```
CALL SP_TESTING();
```

Shows NULL as result (expected since it is not returning anything).
But then when I check the table again:

```
select count(*) from citibike_trips where end_station_id=6215;
```

returns: 0

Comment: Hi @Sergiu,

i have validated again that:
1. my query returns values
2.  target table has data matching my DELETE statement.


i also created the table you used in your example 

'''
CREATE TABLE citibike_trips 
(
    end_station_id NUMBER(6,0)
);

INSERT OVERWRITE INTO citibike_trips 
(
    SELECT 6215
    UNION 
    SELECT 6214
    UNION
    SELECT 6213 
);
'''


and used the SP you created, and it works.
yet, when i rerun my SP, the matching data is not deleted,
any idea what it can cause it?
thanks again

Comment: @ItayAv Is it possible to show us some sample of data returned by first query and also matching data using a SELECT rather than DELETE statement?

Comment: i found the issue with your help, the values were rounded by snowflake ( it was a NUMBER(19,0) TYPE), when i cast it to VARCHAR, not rounding was made, and the records were deleted. 
thanks!